# Decomposing $\frac{(\omega-1)^2}{(1+\omega^2)^2}$ into partial fractions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-fractions

How can I decompose
$$\frac{(\omega-1)^2}{(1+\omega^2)^2}$$
into partial fractions?

Should I solve
$$\frac{A\omega + B}{1+\omega^2} + \frac{C\omega^3 + D\omega^2 + E\omega + D}{(1+\omega^2)^2} = \frac{(\omega-1)^2}{(1+\omega^2)^2}$$

It seems a bit complicated, and if that's indeed the case what is the rationale behind it?

I tried with a CAS and got
$$\frac1{1+\omega^2} - \frac{2\omega}{(1+\omega^2)^2}$$
but it's beyond me how that can be achieved!

Comment: $\frac{(\omega-1)^2}{(1+\omega^2)^2} = \frac{(1+\omega^2) - 2\omega}{(1+\omega^2)^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{ (1 + w^2) - 2w}{(1 + w^2)^2} =   \frac{1}{(1 + w^2)} -  \frac{2w}{(1 + w^2)^2}$$

Comment: I feel dumb, this is indeed the fastest way!

Comment: Don't feel! We are all learning here! You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

the right ansatz is $$\frac{A\omega+B}{1+\omega^2}+\frac{C\omega+D}{(1+\omega^2)^2}$$

Comment: Ah ok, that looks simpler indeed.